# Keras/TF: Can I ignore "topological sort failed" error?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Sometimes I get an error, "topological sort failed with error: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order". Things appear to work anyway, but I've seen comments on other forums that the weights don't update properly when this error is shown.  Anyone know if the message can be safely ignored?